# Python is printing letter on each line

Tags: python

I am trying to get the first mp4 and txt file in the folder, and that works.
But when I print it it will just print every letter of the file name on a different line.
Here is the code:

```
import os
import glob
import instabot
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
path = 'PATH'

#This downloads all files saved
os.system("instaloader --login USERNAME --password PASSWORD :saved")
os.chdir(path)

for file in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    os.remove(file)

for file in glob.glob('*.xz'):
    os.remove(file)

for file in glob.glob('*.mp4')[0]:
    print(file)

for file in glob.glob('*.txt')[0]:
    print(file)
```

So yeah you can test the code if you want, but you do have to have installed os, instaloader, and instabot. So if someone could help me that would be great!

Thanks guys! :)

Edit: Ok I want to be more clear because there was some confusion in the comments, alot of people are suggesting I simply remove the [0] which works but if I do not add that then it will print every single file in the folder. So I need a way to address the first mp4 and txt file in the folder. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import os
import glob
import instabot
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
path = 'PATH'

#This downloads all files saved
os.system("instaloader --login USERNAME --password PASSWORD :saved")
os.chdir(path)

for file in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    os.remove(file)

for file in glob.glob('*.xz'):
    os.remove(file)

for file in glob.glob('*.mp4'):
    print(file)

for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    print(file)
```

Remove the `[0]`, your loop was looping through each character of the first file name (`glob.glob('*.mp4')[0]` is a string so `file` will be each character.

For example if there are file names a.mp4, b.mp4, the use of `glob.glob('*.mp4')[0]` will only give you `a.mp4`, when put into the for loop, it will loop through each of the characters so, a,.,m,p,4, etc

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but I have like 8 mp4 and txt files in this folder and just trying to get the first mp4 and txt file. And with this, it will list all of the files in the directory.

Comment: @GiovanniBarberio If you want to get the first then don’t put it into a for loop, just use `print(glob.glob('*.txt')[0])` and same thing for mp4

Answer (score 1):

Remove [0] from your print loops. By calling for the item at index 0, you are effectively looping through the file name of the first file - on iterating on a single string (Filename - 0 ), you are getting characters.

```
import os
import glob
import instabot
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
path = 'PATH'

#This downloads all files saved
os.system("instaloader --login USERNAME --password PASSWORD :saved")
os.chdir(path)

for file in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    os.remove(file)

for file in glob.glob('*.xz'):
    os.remove(file)

for file in glob.glob('*.mp4'):
    print(file)

for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    print(file)
```

Answer (score -2):

Correction: [0] will only pick first file that is of extension .mp4 or .txt. So if your file name is abc.txt, it will print it as:
a
b
c
.
t
x
t
No idea missing newline in answer, but you get idea with above 2 uders proper code example.

Comment: This is inaccurate, when used with [0], only the first file name is looped through, and then it loops through each character of the file name. NOT the first characters of EACH file name

Comment: Ahh, you are correct. I should have ran a sample before posting.